# This PDE crashes Kernel

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, warning-messages, crash

**Bug introduced in v9.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

I use NDSolve on this simple set of PDEs:

```
NDSolve[{f[z, t] + g[z, t] + D[g[z, t], t] + D[g[z, t], {t, 2}] == 0, 
  D[f[z, t], z] == D[g[z, t], t], f[0, t] == E^(-30 (t - 0.5)^2) - E^-7.5, 
  Derivative[1, 0][f][z, 0] == 0, g[z, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][g][z, 0] == 0},
  {f, g}, {z, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

However, I get
*NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations.*

Followed by
*Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.*

And the Kernel crashes. I've been fighting with this for hours and now I give up. If someone can help me, I will appreciate a lot!

Comment: the kernel crashes also on my 10.4.1 with Windows 10. Regardless of the PDE in case being solvable with this method or not (I haven't checked) the kernel should not crash while trying to evaluate it, so it would probably be useful to also contact the [Wolfram support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/) and report this.

Comment: Crash also on _Mathematica_ 11.0.

Comment: I can not reproduce the crash on Linux with either 10.4.1 nor with 11.0. It's best to report this to the support so they can help figure out what the issue it.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce the crash on Linux, do you obtain any result from the calculation?

Comment: I have filed a bug report for the crash.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is introduced in *v9*. *v8* just returns unevaluated after some warnings. OK, let alone the crash, this PDE set can be solved with the help of `LaplaceTransform`:

```
ic = {Derivative[1, 0][f][z, 0] == 0, g[z, 0] == 0, 
       Derivative[0, 1][g][z, 0] == 0}; 

teqn = LaplaceTransform[{f[z, t] + g[z, t] + D[g[z, t], t] + D[g[z, t], {t, 2}] == 0, 
     D[f[z, t], z] == D[g[z, t], t], f[0, t] == E^(-30 (t - 5/10)^2) - 1/E^(75/10)}, t, 
    s] /. Rule @@@ ic /. HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a

tsol = DSolve[teqn, {f[z, t], g[z, t]}, z][[1, All, -1]] // Simplify
```

`tsol` is a list of transformed solution. The last step is to transform back, but sadly `InverseLaplaceTransform` can't handle `tsol`, so I use `GWR` in [this package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4738/).

```
{tfuncf, tfuncg} = Function[{s, z}, #] & /@ tsol;

solf[t_, z_] := GWR[tfuncf[#, z] &, t]    
solg[t_, z_] := GWR[tfuncg[#, z] &, t]

With[{eps = 10^-3}, 
    ListPlot3D[ParallelTable[#1[t, z], {t, eps, 1 + eps, 1/25}, {z, 0, 1, 1/25}], 
     DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]] & /@ {solf, solg} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want to improve my answer if possible.